# ListAdapter - I dont know what my App crash

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, listadapter

I need help on the reason my app crash. I can see it complains about the array index bigger than 16, but wherein the code? I don't know.

I basically request Bluetooth data, then after the data arrive, It opens an Activity displaying the data in a Listview. The App crash when the Listview tries to launch.

I will provide code if needed.
Thanx

Here is my LogCat

```
2021-04-14 16:57:40.160 26029-26058/com.example.ble D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 8899172237312
2021-04-14 16:57:47.225 26029-26058/com.example.ble D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x750a612200,api=1)
2021-04-14 16:57:47.226 26029-26058/com.example.ble D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x7508bc39c0) (w:812 h:610 s:816 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
2021-04-14 16:57:47.226 26029-26058/com.example.ble D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x7508ba0540) (w:812 h:610 s:816 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
2021-04-14 16:57:47.227 26029-26058/com.example.ble D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x7508ba2040) (w:812 h:610 s:816 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
2021-04-14 16:57:47.227 26029-26058/com.example.ble D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x750a612200,api=1)
2021-04-14 16:57:47.239 26029-26029/com.example.ble D/WindowClient: Remove from mViews: DecorView@7724e1e[], this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@d68a129
2021-04-14 16:57:47.240 26029-26041/com.example.ble I/art: Enter while loop.
2021-04-14 16:57:47.250 26029-26029/com.example.ble V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=32 first=false flags=#81810100
2021-04-14 16:57:47.399 26029-26058/com.example.ble D/OpenGLRenderer: ~CanvasContext() 0x751f97c000
2021-04-14 16:57:47.411 26029-26058/com.example.ble D/OpenGLRenderer: ~CanvasContext() 0x751f975000
2021-04-14 16:57:47.412 26029-26058/com.example.ble D/OpenGLRenderer: ~CanvasContext() 0x751f978800
2021-04-14 16:57:47.414 26029-26058/com.example.ble D/OpenGLRenderer: ~CanvasContext() 0x751f971800
2021-04-14 16:57:48.212 26029-26104/com.example.ble D/HomeFragment: ReadHolding Task Start
2021-04-14 16:57:48.212 26029-26104/com.example.ble D/Service_BTLE_GATT: Clear Buffers
2021-04-14 16:57:48.213 26029-26104/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: writeCharacteristic() - uuid: 2456e1b9-26e2-8f83-e744-f34f01e9d703
2021-04-14 16:57:48.215 26029-26043/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: onCharacteristicWrite() - Device=CC:F9:57:8E:60:C9 handle=25 Status=0
2021-04-14 16:57:48.310 26029-26042/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: onNotify() - Device=CC:F9:57:8E:60:C9 handle=25
2021-04-14 16:57:48.310 26029-26042/com.example.ble D/Service_BTLE_GATT: QTY Bytes in rx_Data = 20
2021-04-14 16:57:48.312 26029-26043/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: onNotify() - Device=CC:F9:57:8E:60:C9 handle=25
2021-04-14 16:57:48.312 26029-26043/com.example.ble D/Service_BTLE_GATT: QTY Bytes in rx_Data = 11
2021-04-14 16:57:48.313 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 0, 0xfa
2021-04-14 16:57:48.314 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 1, 0x 3
2021-04-14 16:57:48.315 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 2, 0x1a
2021-04-14 16:57:48.316 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 3, 0x64
2021-04-14 16:57:48.316 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 4, 0x 0
2021-04-14 16:57:48.317 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 5, 0x 1
2021-04-14 16:57:48.318 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 6, 0x 0
2021-04-14 16:57:48.319 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 7, 0x 1
2021-04-14 16:57:48.320 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 8, 0x 0
2021-04-14 16:57:48.320 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 9, 0x7c
2021-04-14 16:57:48.321 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 10, 0x 1
2021-04-14 16:57:48.322 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 11, 0x 1
2021-04-14 16:57:48.322 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 12, 0x 0
2021-04-14 16:57:48.323 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 13, 0x 1
2021-04-14 16:57:48.324 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 14, 0x 0
2021-04-14 16:57:48.324 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 15, 0x 0
2021-04-14 16:57:48.325 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 16, 0x 0
2021-04-14 16:57:48.326 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 17, 0x15
2021-04-14 16:57:48.326 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 18, 0x 0
2021-04-14 16:57:48.327 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 19, 0x1e
2021-04-14 16:57:48.327 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 20, 0x 0
2021-04-14 16:57:48.328 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 21, 0x 0
2021-04-14 16:57:48.329 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 22, 0x 0
2021-04-14 16:57:48.330 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 23, 0x 0
2021-04-14 16:57:48.330 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 24, 0x 0
2021-04-14 16:57:48.331 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 25, 0x28
2021-04-14 16:57:48.331 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 26, 0x 0
2021-04-14 16:57:48.332 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 27, 0x 1
2021-04-14 16:57:48.333 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 28, 0x 0
2021-04-14 16:57:48.334 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 29, 0xd6
2021-04-14 16:57:48.335 26029-26043/com.example.ble I/ModbusHandler: Decode Message ByteNum: 30, 0x58
2021-04-14 16:57:48.335 26029-26043/com.example.ble D/ModbusHandler: CRC GOOD QTY: 1
2021-04-14 16:57:48.335 26029-26043/com.example.ble D/ModbusHandler: Populate Holding Resister Block nr: 0
2021-04-14 16:57:48.335 26029-26043/com.example.ble D/Service_BTLE_GATT: Clear Buffers
2021-04-14 16:57:48.355 26029-26037/com.example.ble I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
2021-04-14 16:57:48.355 26029-26037/com.example.ble I/art: Enter while loop.
2021-04-14 16:57:48.495 26029-26029/com.example.ble D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
2021-04-14 16:57:48.498 26029-26029/com.example.ble D/BluetoothAdapter: getLeState() returning 12
2021-04-14 16:57:48.498 26029-26029/com.example.ble D/BluetoothAdapter: scan not started yet
2021-04-14 16:57:48.629 26029-26029/com.example.ble D/Activity_ListViewInp: Start Input ListAdapter on CT VT and Relay 1
2021-04-14 16:57:48.659 26029-26029/com.example.ble V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = null, this = DecorView@79093fe[]
2021-04-14 16:57:48.662 26029-26029/com.example.ble D/WindowClient: Add to mViews: DecorView@79093fe[Activity_ListViewInp], this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@d68a129
2021-04-14 16:57:48.664 26029-26058/com.example.ble D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0x751f971800
2021-04-14 16:57:48.665 26029-26029/com.example.ble D/ViewRootImpl[Activity_ListViewInp]: hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{a122228 com.example.ble/com.example.ble.Activity_ListViewInp,ident = 6}
2021-04-14 16:57:48.669 26029-26029/com.example.ble V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = ViewRoot{a122228 com.example.ble/com.example.ble.Activity_ListViewInp,ident = 6}, this = DecorView@79093fe[Activity_ListViewInp]
2021-04-14 16:57:48.684 26029-26058/com.example.ble D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x7526255c00,api=1)
2021-04-14 16:57:48.685 26029-26058/com.example.ble D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x75086fbe00) (w:720 h:1280 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
2021-04-14 16:57:48.685 26029-26058/com.example.ble D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x7508664100) (w:720 h:1280 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
2021-04-14 16:57:48.685 26029-26058/com.example.ble D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x7508ba09c0) (w:720 h:1280 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
2021-04-14 16:57:48.685 26029-26058/com.example.ble D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x7526255c00,api=1)
2021-04-14 16:57:48.825 26029-26029/com.example.ble W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int androidx.appcompat.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
2021-04-14 16:57:48.952 26029-26029/com.example.ble D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-04-14 16:57:48.964 26029-26029/com.example.ble E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ble, PID: 26029
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=16; index=16
        at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:7424)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1361)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1250)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:511)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:490)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:714)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2640)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1577)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1846)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1462)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6965)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:907)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:709)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:644)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:893)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
2021-04-14 16:57:49.212 26029-26104/com.example.ble D/HomeFragment: ReadHolding Task Start
2021-04-14 16:57:49.212 26029-26104/com.example.ble D/Service_BTLE_GATT: Clear Buffers
2021-04-14 16:57:49.213 26029-26104/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: writeCharacteristic() - uuid: 2456e1b9-26e2-8f83-e744-f34f01e9d703
2021-04-14 16:57:49.215 26029-26043/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: onCharacteristicWrite() - Device=CC:F9:57:8E:60:C9 handle=25 Status=0
2021-04-14 16:57:49.310 26029-26042/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: onNotify() - Device=CC:F9:57:8E:60:C9 handle=25
2021-04-14 16:57:49.311 26029-26042/com.example.ble D/Service_BTLE_GATT: QTY Bytes in rx_Data = 20
2021-04-14 16:57:49.313 26029-26076/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: onNotify() - Device=CC:F9:57:8E:60:C9 handle=25
2021-04-14 16:57:49.314 26029-26076/com.example.ble D/Service_BTLE_GATT: QTY Bytes in rx_Data = 8
2021-04-14 16:57:49.316 26029-26043/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: onNotify() - Device=CC:F9:57:8E:60:C9 handle=25
2021-04-14 16:57:49.317 26029-26043/com.example.ble D/Service_BTLE_GATT: QTY Bytes in rx_Data = 1
```

Comment: "When appropriate, share the minimum amount of code others need to reproduce your problem", it is need in this case

Comment: Hi javdromero, I found my problem, I have 17 different Layouts that can be added to my ListAdapter, but I return only 16 in getViewTypeCount().